# How can I get the data previously written by Hyperledger Composer bna from Fabric chaincode Invoke function

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have prototyped a basic network using Hyperledger Composer and now working on migration of the solution to completely Fabric-based.

Since there is a network with pre-published testing data, I just composed a new CC in Golang and copy the sources into my channel's peer for deploying it.
Peer is connected to `composer_default` network's channel, which was created by **composer-tools/fabric-dev-servers** `startFabric.sh` script.

Then I replaced my bna chaincode from Fabric network by Golang chaincode build, with using the same CC name and incremented CC version (`peer chaincode upgrade`).

So the question is: does it possible for the new Fabric CC to get through existing State filed by Composer bna previously? Like we access it using GetState method of ChaincodeStubInterface:

```
marbleAsBytes, err := stub.GetState(marbleName)
```

Or perhaps the data can be pulled with Queries to CouchDB (channel's current store)? Don't know the real key identifiers used by Composer to store their write sets.

P.S. Actually I don't want to invoke Composer bna transactions/queries from Fabric CC and vice versa. It's just a kind of upgrade of business logic for existing network environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be possible as assets are stored as key value pairs, you can first try to query any key through native golang chaincode. As previously I had tried upgrading one composer chaincode with completely different chaincode, and if I tried entering data for previously used key in my old composer chaincode, it was throwing error. So even if the chaincode is different you should be able to access the already created asset through its key.